# A SQL Problem. Check condition with in a comma seperated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a vairable

```
DECLARE @AssignOn nvarchar(20)='0,2,5'
```

I want to check a condition like this

```
DECLARE @index int
SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT @index=DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())-1
IF(CONVERT(nvarchar(2),@index) IN @AssignOn)
```

IN cannot be used here . Any other methods to do this `INLINE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to search for the substring ',*needle*,' in the csv list string. However, this doesn't work correctly for the first and last elements. This can be overcome by concatenating a comma onto each side of the csv list string.

An example in SQL might be:

```
SELECT
    CHARINDEX(','+ NEEDLE +',', ','+ HAYSTACK +',')
FROM table;
```

Or using LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ','+ HAYSTACK +',' LIKE '%,'+ NEEDLE +',';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CharIndex to find if you have a match. It returns a non zero value if the first string appears in the second.

```
IF(CHARINDEX(CONVERT(nvarchar(2),@index), @AssignOn) > 0)
```

Comment: I think this is only a suitable solution if the integer values delimited in @AssignOn range from 0-9.

Comment: @Curt - They are limited to 0-6 since `@index=DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF CHARINDEX(','+CONVERT(nvarchar(2),@index)+',', ','+@AssignOn+',') <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you actually define the values in the code you could instead;

```
DECLARE @AssignOn TABLE (value int)
   INSERT @AssignOn VALUES (0),(2),(5)

... @index IN (SELECT value FROM @AssignOn)
```